# How to straighten a grouped gvim Buffers menu?

Tags: vim

The GUI version of Vim has a "Buffers" menu where there's a menu item for each *buffer* - as long as there aren't too many; when there are more than a certain number, the buffer items are grouped into sub-menus "abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop", "qrst" and "u-z" according to the file names' initials.

After that grouping happened, how can I straighten the menu again, so that the buffer items are unfolded and there are no sub-menus?

(I tried `:set menuitems=` a higher number and `:menu disable/enable Buffers` without avail.)

Comment: _The GUI version of Vim_. Which one? There are plenty.

Comment: @sidyll Every version of Vim 6 and Vim 7 I came across on HPUX, Linux and Windows has this menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to reduce the number of listed buffers, e.g. via `:bdelete`. Once the number is below `&menuitems`, you can recreate the menu via *Buffers > Refresh menu*. Then, the submenus will be gone.

If that doesn't fit you, you can fork and adapt the menu code, and build your own. The code can be found in `$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim`.